# Is Loki faster and slimmer than Freya?

Tags: release-freya, release-loki

my question may seem a bit plain, but to those who have tested the loki beta already: What is your impression? Is is faster and slimer than freya?

I installed freya a few months ago on my laptop bercause I got told its one of the fastest and lightest Linux distros (excpet of cause those without a GUI). I am very happy so far, because it kept up to those promises and runs like a charm on my laptop with limited resources, worked very well out of the box and well on top is nice to look at.

So to those who have used the beta so far: Whats your impression? Did Loki improve regarding to speed and lightweightness?

Answer (score 1):

Just by seeing beta release, we can't say anything about speed and resource affinity of a distribution. Because, beta release usually comes with a lot of debugging flags enabled which significantly affects performance.

Personally, what I felt is that `Loki` is more resource consuming, but I don't have any statistical information to prove it.

Wait for the final release, and then you can decide which one is better in terms of resources usage and speed.